# Console.log = null for a value I manually set

Tags: javascript, jquery, console.log

Any thoughts on why this console.log returns null?

```
$("select[name='manager']").val("Bob"); // Should set input select to value "Bob"`
```

`console.log($("select[name='manager']")); // Logs: null`

Comment: If `$("select[name='manager']")` selects nothing, it will be null. Are you sure the selector is valid?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not saving your selection in a variable. The first line basically does nothing and your second line is empty because it didn't select anything. Try this instead:

```
var value = $("select[name='manager']").val("Bob");
console.log(value);
```

or you can do this:

```
console.log($("select[name='manager']").val("Bob"));
```